# Atlas for a stack of sheaves of rank 1 with torsion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, algebraic-stacks

I would like to construct an atlas for the stack of sheaves E of rank 1 and degree b on an elliptic curve C such that E has torsion of length at most 1. Am I allowed to fix both the determinant L of the sheaf E and the point x on C where E possibly has torsion? In that case I would construct an atlas as PHom(L(-2x),F) where F is the unique nontrivial extension of L(-x) by L(-x). Would this help me to construct an atlas for the original stack? If not, could you suggest a different way to construct an atlas for the original stack?